# "Be the first to review this product" is not working for me

Tags: magento2, review

I'm using Magento 2. Product review button is not working for me. When I click on it re-directs to the same page.

Anyone can help me to resolve this problem?

Comment: you can check in console or error log

Comment: It is showing error like this
Refused to apply style from 'http://magento.zoohause.co.uk/pub/media/vicomage/css_config/design_default.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.

Comment: here review tab is missing

Comment: How can we get it back. Can you please explain me in briefly.

Comment: you have disabled in xml file or theme's xml file disable

Comment: How can I enable xml file?

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 2):

Review block will not work in custom Magento 2 theme.

To show Review tab on the product page you should have to add JsLayout at the following location.

> app/design/frontend/{Vendor}/{theme}/Magento_Review/layout/catalog_product_view.xml

Add the following code in above located file.

```
<referenceBlock name="product.review.form">
 <arguments>
    <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="review-form" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Review/js/view/review</item>
            </item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</arguments>
</referenceBlock>
```

Comment: In my app structure, In this location app/design/frontend/{Vendor}/{theme}/Magento_Review/layout/
I have files like this 1. review_customer_view.xml 2. review_customer_index.xml

Comment: There is no catalog_product_view.xml file

Comment: you can create and override file

Comment: should I create catalog_product_view.xml file and upload it into the server?

Comment: @RakeshDonga, same issue for me, after clicking the tab is not getting opened

Comment: any update on this? i have the same issue